# iPhone App Shows a white light dot when the iphone is woke up from sleep mode

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am not sure whether this is a strange case,but this is the scenario.

1. I open my iPhone app in my iPhone device and i work on the app
2. I Lock my iPhone device and I try to unlock the phone from sleep mode
3. When the unlock is successful, I see a white light of size 3 to 4 pixels in the center of the screen and from that point the app resumes.

What would be the reason for this error, kindly help.

Comment: This is not a programming question. Voting to move to superuser.com

Comment: Hi Alex,

Thanks for your response and about superuser.com.
I have the above issue in my iphone device for my app only, other apps work fine when resumed from sleep mode. I still feel there will be a programatic solution to this. kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This didn't happen after a specific amount of time - no clue why it came up.